# django aggregation on App Engine

Tags: django, performance, google-app-engine, aggregation

I m trying to calculate sum of a list of records. I have 3 options

1. customer= Customer.objects.all()
    Then loop through this list and calculate sum
2. Using aggregation 
    Total = Customer.objects.aggregate(Sum('amount'))
3. Using Annotate 
   Customer.objects.annotate(Sum('amount'))

My question is
1. Annotate and aggregation, which one is faster ?
2. I can't use aggregate in django, it throws This database can not use aggregation. I'm using datastore of Google app engine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3 is not an option. Annotating applies per object, so you'd still have to sum the 'amount' via python.

Since you say aggregation isn't possible, that leaves you with one choice:

```
total = sum((x.amount for x in Customer.objects.all())
```

Or go to raw GQL, which I don't know :D

Comment: Do you think this is a bit slower than execute sum query in the database :-)

Comment: The database is definitely faster. Definitely look into raw GQL if this is performance critical. Otherwise, meh, a report here and there, I don't mind the python.

Comment: GQL does not do aggregation.  It's just a wrapper to use an SQL-like syntax to construct the same kind of query you get with `.all()`.